# How to access first element in iterator?

Tags: php, iterator

I'm using a PHP framework that returns SQL results as iteratable objects. Problem is I have a SQL query that that returns one row and I don't want to have to create a `foreach`-loop to get at the first - and only - element.

So how do I do it?

These don't work:

```
$obj->item(0)->propName;
$obj->next()->propName;
$obj[0]->propName;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$obj->current()->propName` perhaps?

Comment: put a `var_dump` and check the structure of the result object

Comment: Crisp's answer did the trick. Make that a sep answer and I'll mark it as the answer. var_dump gave me useless junk like this:  http://pastebin.com/GeNDbiN4

Comment: Meh, someone's already given the same answer, seems a bit redundant to write it again, glad it helped though @neubert

Comment: @Crisp It looks like you posted first. I'd be happy to delete my answer if you would like to post one yourself.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: I'd only be copying and pasting yours, it's a well written answer, take the plaudits mate, I'm cool with that

Comment: @Crisp Cool, thanks. Also, 'plaudits' is now my word of the day.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming by "iterable", you mean that the object implements the [`Iterator` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php), you can use `$obj->current()` to retrieve the current element, so `$obj->current()->propName` is probably what you want.

If the iterator pointer has been moved (for example, if it was used in a `foreach`, which doesn't reset the pointer), then you can call `$obj->rewind()` to set the pointer back to the first element before you call `$obj->current()`.

Answer (score 19):

There are only **two** class interfaces that can be traversed: [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and  [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) (*any other must implement one of them*).

---

## Iterator

First element of Iterator can be obtained as follows:

```
$iterator->rewind();
if (!$iterator->valid()) {
    throw new Exception('There is no any element!');
}
$firstElement = $iterator->current();
```

If you are sure:

- the `$iterator` was never been traversed by `foreach`, or if it was but the loop was never stopped with `break` or `return` (*since PHP 7 this point is irrelevant because foreach does not affect pointer*)
- there was never called `$iterator->next();`

you can omit the `$iterator->rewind();` from the previous example.

If you are sure the count of elements in `$iterator` is **not** zero, you can even omit the condition block testing `$iterator->valid()`.

So if these previous conditions are preserved then what you need is just:

```
$firstElement = $iterator->current();
```

---

## IteratorAggregate

IteratorAggergate is actually just an envelope for an Iterator or another IteratorAggregate. Logically that means there is an Iterator at the end.

If you know how many levels deep the Iterator is, just grab it and use as in the very first example:

```
$iterator = $iteratorAggregate->getIterator();
```

But if you don't know the deepness, you may use a solution which works also for an Iterator:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($iteratorAggregate);
// $array is an ordinary array now
if (count($array) === 0) {
    throw new Exception('There is no any element!');
}
$firstElement = reset($array);
```

**Unfortunately** in case of biig array this is a little **overkill** because copy of all elements must be created despite we need just one. Besides if the Iterator is an infinite [Generator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php) you will run out of memory.

There is one solution that works:

```
while ($iterator instanceof \IteratorAggregate) {
    $iterator = $iterator->getIterator();
}
// $iterator now contains instance of Iterator
```

I made a simple benchmark for an array of 10000 members and this solution was almost 6 times faster.

So, the universal solution which will work for all cases is:

```
while ($iterator instanceof \IteratorAggregate) {
    $iterator = $iterator->getIterator();
}
$iterator->rewind();
if (!$iterator->valid()) {
    throw new Exception('There is no any element!');
}
$firstElement = $iterator->current();
```

*LLAP*

Answer (score 2):

For any types of iterables(`array`, `Iterator`, `IteratorAggregate`) you can use this function:

```php
/* public static */ function first(iterable $iterable, $default = null) {
    foreach ($iterable as $item){
        return $item;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

If you prefer to throw an exception if iterable is empty, you can use that version:

```php
/* public static */ function firstOrThrow(iterable $iterable, \Throwable $e) {
    foreach ($iterable as $item){
        return $item;
    }
    throw $e;
}
```

That works both for arrays and iterator objects and also computes only first item in iterators which can improve performance is some cases.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing this, which I personally find less verbose is to convert the iterator to an array first and then check if the array is empty or not.

```
$result = iterator_to_array($iterator, true);
if(!empty($result)){
   $user = end($result)->id;
}
```

Pretty useful when you know your iterator will return only one 'iteration'. However, if you are going to have thousands, be cautious that you'll be populating an array with all the data first which might increase your memory usage until the array if empty again.